# dotnet sonarscanner did not find java but JAVA_HOME exists. Tried jre 11,13, 17 on ubuntu 20.04.3

Tags: software-installation, jre, dotnet

I am starting proper command

> ~/project$ /usr/bin/dotnet sonarscanner end /d:sonar.login="admin" /d:sonar.password="user"

and got the java error on ubuntu 20.04.3

> SonarScanner for MSBuild 5.2.2 Using the .NET Core version of the Scanner for MSBuild Post-processing started. Calling the SonarScanner CLI... Could not find 'java' executable in JAVA_HOME or PATH. The SonarScanner did not complete successfully 20:05:32.56 Post-processing failed. Exit code: 1

There are SonarQube 8.9.10 in docker and .net 5 global tool sonarscanner 5.2.2.

JAVA_HOME and PATH were set to the same java elf dynamic shared object with chmod +x. What's wrong? Thank you.

---

`java --version`

> openjdk 11.0.21 2023-10-17
> OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.21+9-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu120.04)
> OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.21+9-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu120.04, mixed mode, sharing)

`echo $PATH`

> /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java

`echo $JAVA_HOME`

> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java

Applied `sudo chmod +x /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java`

Comment: What does `java --version` give you? And what do you mean by "JAVA_HOME and PATH were set to the same java elf dynamic shared object with chmod +x"? Please clarify this by editing your question.

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu 20.04?  as your details (20.04.3) imply you've not applied any security fixes since **before** February 2022; https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/02/25/ubuntu-20-04-4-lts-released/ shows the ISO release date of 20.04.4, but installed systems upgraded **before** that date. If using Ubuntu 20.04, I'll suggest applying all security updates asap & trying again.

Comment: @zwets, question updated.

Comment: @guiverc, I use and I should use Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS. It is strong requirement now.

Comment: AFAIK `JAVA_HOME` and `PATH` should contain *directories* not binaries ex. `JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64` and `PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin`

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS is your release; the .3 only shows your upgrade level; and .3 shows you've not applied security fixes to your 20.04 system for some time.  The release is the *year.month* part, ie. 20.04 for the 2020-April release.  If you read the link I provided it said "*As usual, this point release includes many updates, and updated installation media has been provided so that fewer updates will need to be downloaded after installation*"  ie. those are **updates and security fixes you've not applied to your 20.04 system**...  (and an updated system currently reports as 20.04.6

Comment: If you installed the default Java (`default-jre` or `default-jdk`) using apt, there is no need to change `PATH` or set `JAVA_HOME`, and certainly no need to `chmod` system files. The `/usr/bin`, `/usr/lib`, etc directories are managed by APT. Don't touch what is there. `apt install default-jre` gives you the `java` command and that's all a Java application jar should need to run.

Comment: @steeldriver, thanks. Still not working in that case.

Comment: @zwets, I have tried this, but error still exists.

Comment: I am using Community edition. Do I need to build and put elsewhere C# driver?